# findIndex() always return -1 on array with objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I don't find the solution on following problem. The index keeps returning -1 instead of 1 in this case.

Anyone that can help me out?

```js
let allRules = [{ruleName: "a"}, {ruleName: "b"}, {ruleName: "c"}]
let name = "b"
let index = allRules.findIndex(x => {
  console.log(x.ruleName)
  x.ruleName === name
})
console.log(index)
```

Comment: you need to `return x.ruleName === name`

Comment: `x => x.ruleName === name`

Comment: This a a great article to understand when you need to use brackets or return to your arrow functions

https://codeburst.io/javascript-understand-arrow-function-syntax-ab4081bba85b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `return` keyword as you have `{}` in your callback method:

```js
let allRules = [{ruleName: "a"}, {ruleName: "b"}, {ruleName: "c"}]
let name = "b"
let index = allRules.findIndex(x => {
  console.log(x.ruleName)
  return x.ruleName == name
})
console.log(index)
```

An example without `return` statement:

```js
let allRules = [{ruleName: "a"}, {ruleName: "b"}, {ruleName: "c"}]
let name = "b"
let index = allRules.findIndex(x => x.ruleName == name)
console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add return.

```
let allRules = [{ruleName: "a"}, {ruleName: "b"}, {ruleName: "c"}]
let name = "b"
let index = allRules.findIndex(x => {
  console.log(x.ruleName)
  return x.ruleName === name
})
console.log(index)
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Nick Parsons in comments said you need to `return` something.

```js
let allRules = [{ruleName: "a"}, {ruleName: "b"}, {ruleName: "c"}]
let name = "b"
let index = allRules.findIndex(x => {
  console.log(x.ruleName);
  return x.ruleName === name;
})
console.log(index)
```